# AVAssetDownloadDelegate method not called in background

Tags: ios, swift, avassetdownloadtask, avassetdownloadurlsession

In a recent project I'm working on video downloading using `AVAssetDownloadURLSession`. I'm using `AVAssetDownloadDelegate` to listen to any download updates. Using the below method I'm able to get the percentage download updated for each download task.

[urlSession(_:aggregateAssetDownloadTask:didLoad:totalTimeRangesLoaded:timeRangeExpectedToLoad:for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetdownloaddelegate/2919988-urlsession)

**Issue:**

The above method doesn't get called when the app is in Background. There is nothing mentioned in the Apple docs regarding the method's foreground and background behaviour.

How can I clarify how the method works? And what is the way around if I want to get the background updated as well?

Comment: Did you test it on real device or simulator?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak On the real device.

Comment: And did you set identifier for your session?

Comment: @Mr.SwiftOak Yes we used an identifier while creating the session.